# JFrog Artifactory redirecting to /webapps but not loading

Tags: docker, docker-compose, artifactory

I am running JFrog on a Ubuntu vm using docker compose. Below is the docker-compose.yaml for it.

```
version: '3'
services:
  artifactory:
    image: docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-oss:6.17.0
    container_name: artifactory
    ports:
     - 80:8081
    volumes:
     - /data/artifactory:/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory
    restart: always
    ulimits:
      nproc: 65535
      nofile:
        soft: 32000
        hard: 40000
```

The /data/artifactory folder was there, I gave it 777 permissions. For the /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory path, jfrog and artifactory folders were not there automatically. So, I created those two blank folders in /var/opt and gave them 777. However, whenever I hit the jfrog url from my browser,

```
i.e. my-site/artifactory
```

it redirects to my-site/artifactory/webapp and there, it shows a blank page and the loading icon on the tab (browser) keeps spinning. Like that, the page keeps loading forever but never loads.

What is going wrong? The container is running, I checked using `docker ps -a`.

Comment: can you check the artifactory container logs if any errors are seen?

Comment: The last log was, Artifactory successfully started. After that, "Starting docker temp folder cleanup" and "cleanup finished".